# Select dropdown option with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm kinda new at Selenium, so a proposed myself a project. I'm trying to get as much information as I can from this URL https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/proventos/ibovespa

Until that time I was able to do everything, EXCEPT change the default option at the "Filtro por Índice". I would like to change it from "Ibovespa" to "--GERAL--" but it has been harder than I would expect! I tried via classical XPath (find then click) and by the Select() class in Selenium, but it appears to be beyound my knowledge and I'm totally stuck...

Anyone has any tip on how to accomplish it?

Thanks!

Comment: So the item is not a select object, therefore using `Select()` wouldn't work. You would have to first click the `input` tag, than click on the `li` tag that you want.

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful! I was trying to use Select() or find by XPath but I didn't notice the li tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a very simple way to change the input option would be to do:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

select_obj = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'select-wrapper') # object that contains all of the elements for first input selector
select_obj.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input').click() # click the input object to bring up the options
select_obj.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')[0].click() # click the first option
```